# Where do Outlook folders go when moved?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have an account with external user mailboxes opened and accidentally I have moved a folder and now I can't find it anywhere.

*Action:*

- I clicked on a folder and dragged it into another one.

*Result:*

- Can't find the moved folder anywhere

[image]

The above picture is the folders I currently have from my **Outlook 2010** (via **Exchange 2010**), under an **AD Network**.

Where can I (*me, having admin rights over the network*) retrieve that missing folder again?

**Attempts:**

The original and the one folder I need was accidentally moved, but I have created a `poi` folder and tried the same way, and I got the same result... the folder went missing.

I also tried to reboot the client machine and access the same mailbox from OWA ... no luck on both attempts :(

> Any ideas on how I can retrieve the missing folder and its emails again?

Answer (score 1):

Expand all the folders in the "Folder view" in Outlook (or preferably OWA).  If it isn't in there then it should be under the Deleted Items folder.  If it isn't there then you would need to restore the Mailbox to get the folder back, but I don't think you'll need to go that far.

Comment: tried that... but I guess I really need to restore the Mailbox then :(

Comment: @balexandre - It's definitely in there somewhere, unless you deleted it from Deleted Items (in which case you'll definitely need to do a restore).  If you're having trouble seeing it, you could try searching the entire mailbox for an e-mail you know should be in that folder to confirm that it's still there.

Answer (score 1):

Really hope this get's indexed by google for the world to see. I had this EXACT ISSUE happen to me, and no solutions worked. Please bear in mind I am my companies I.T. Guy and consider myself to be competent in these things, so I tried all the suggested solutions before even turning to the forums.

Now the way I resolved it was to log on to the outlook (office 365) web dashboard. The folder I had accidentally dragged into another one (Henrys issue folder was dragged into undeliverable folder) WOULD NOT show up in the folder tree, nor were any of the emails within the folder searchable within the desktop app, it had, for all intents and purposes, completely dissapeared, and no it was not in the deleted folder or any other folder. **When I logged into the web portal, I FOUND IT!** Right where I thought it was.

I was using office 2013 desktop apps tied into office 365. This might not work for 2010 or earlier, but 2010 does have a webapp depending on your liscence. Hope this helps aleviates peoples fears as this freaked me out